# exjts hide column if all cells of the column are empty

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to hide the column if all the cells in the column are empty. I am trying to do this in the column listener by iterating through the store but I guess the store isnt populated at that time. any suggestions to achieve this functionality?

```
Ext.define('com.abc.MyGrid' , {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        store : 'MyStore',
    columns : [{
        text : 'col1',
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex : 'col1' 
    }, {
        text : 'col2 ',
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex : 'col2',
                listeners:{
            "beforerender": function(){
                console.log(this.up('grid').store);
                this.up('grid').store.each(function(record,idx){
                                        // if all are null for record.get('col1')
                                        // hide the column
                     console.log(record.get('col1')); 
                });
            }
        } 
    }

})
```

But this is isnt working. Basically the store loop in the column listener "before render" is not executing where as the above console(this.up('grid').store) prints the store with values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, it doesn't handle everything but should be sufficient.

```
Ext.define('HideColumnIfEmpty', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.hideColumnIfEmpty',

    mixins: {
        bindable: 'Ext.util.Bindable'
    },

    init: function(grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
        this._initStates();
        this.grid.on('reconfigure', this._initStates, this);
    },

    _initStates: function(store, columns) {
        var store = this.grid.getStore(),
            columns = this.grid.columns;

        this.bindStore(store);
        this.columns = columns;

        if(store.getCount() > 0) {
            this._maybeHideColumns();
        }
    },
    /**
     *@implement
     */
    getStoreListeners: function() {
        return {
            load: this._maybeHideColumns
        };
    },

    _maybeHideColumns: function() {
        var columns = this.columns,
            store = this.store,
            columnKeysMc = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();

        Ext.Array.forEach(columns, function(column) {
            columnKeysMc.add(column.dataIndex, column);
        });

        Ext.Array.some(store.getRange(),function(record){
            //don't saw off the branch you are sitting on
            //eachKey does not clone
            var keysToRemove = [];

            columnKeysMc.eachKey(function(key) {
                if(!Ext.isEmpty(record.get(key))) {
                    keysToRemove.push(key);
                }
            });

            Ext.Array.forEach(keysToRemove, function(k) {
                columnKeysMc.removeAtKey(k);
            });

            return columnKeysMc.getCount() === 0;
        });

        columnKeysMc.each(function(column) {
            column.hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Here is an example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' },
        { text: 'Says Doh', dataIndex: 'saysDoh'}
    ],
    plugins: {ptype: 'hideColumnIfEmpty'},
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

You can see in the example that saysDoh column is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the store, you need to put a listener on the `load` event of your store. The beforerender doesn't mean that your store is already loaded.

I would put the creation of you store in the initComponent. Something like this:

```
Ext.define('com.abc.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    columns: [{
        text: 'col1',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'col1'
    }, {
        text: 'col2 ',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'col2'
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        //Create store
        var myStore = Ext.create('MyStore');
        myStore.load(); // You can remove this if autoLoad: true on your store.
        //Listen to load event (fires when loading has completed)
        myStore.on({
            load: function (store, records, success) {
                store.each(function (record, idx) {
                    console.log(record.get('col1'));
                });
            }
        });

        //Apply the store to your grid
        Ext.apply(me, {
            store: myStore
        });

        me.callParent();
    }
});
```